# Error: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0) in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I've been struggling with this error for past few days, and I can't seem to find any useful answers online, so any help would be much appreciated!

I'm working with Flutter Web, and I am using [universal_io](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io) package due to dart:io not being supported on the web. With help of an [Image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package I am converting file from Jpg to Png and am trying to convert recieved `Unit8List` of an converted file to an `File` variable. However that doesn't seem to work.

**I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR:**

```
Error: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0)
```

[Full error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY1fU.png)

**WHAT I'M DOING:**
I am trying to convert an **Unit8List** to an **File Variable** with this line:
 `File convertedFile = File.fromRawPath(png);` with `png` being an Unit8List.

**FULL CODE:**

```html
convertFiles() async {
  //1. Requesting file from the internet [✓ works]
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(folderFiles[openFileIndex.value]["link"]),
  );

  //2. Decoding WEBP image with "Image" package [✓ works]
  var image = img.decodeWebP(response.bodyBytes);

  //3. Encoding decoded WEBP file as an PNG [✓ works]
  Uint8List png = img.encodePng(image!) as Uint8List;

  //4. Trying to convert file bytes(Unit8List) to a File Variable [✗ throws an error]
  File convertedFile = File.fromRawPath(png);
}
```

[VSCode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/826ji.png)

**WHAT I TRIED:**
I've tried everything I've seen on the internet including moving to `Master` channel and Upgrading Flutter, but none of those things solved the problem.

**FLUTTER DOCTOR:**

```html
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.5.0-4.0.pre.23, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm64, locale en-SI)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Zin.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the universal.io package, there is already an opened issue, you can track the progress here - [Flutter Web : Unable to convert uint8list to File](https://github.com/dint-dev/universal_io/issues/25).

Meanwhile you can check is this constructor can help you - [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying so fast! I've already tried Image.memory and it works great at what it's supposed to do, but I couldn't find a way to convert that image to a File so that I can upload it to Firebase Storage. Is that conversion even possible?

Comment: Hey @NikGrmek you can use upload raw data [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#uploading_raw_data), so you can skip the conversion.